# Have/ get me considered?

Tags: usage, phrases, alternatives

Something had me considered or something got me considered?

I would like to use the past particle form of 'consider' in the object + participle construction. To express that I was considered for a job/ Uni/ scholarship thanks to good grades, performance, record etc.

I can only thinks of two ways of putting it, and neither of them I find satisfactory. To clarify, below is the kind of sentence I wanted to use:

> This level of performance would GET YOU CONSIDERED/HAVE YOU CONSIDERED for any university in the entire country.

I don't want to use 'get' because it is quite an informal word to use with 'considered', and I am under the impression that to say' have someone considered' would mean that someone arranged for that person to be considered by someone else, which wouldn't work in my case as the subject of my sentence is the factor that led to me being considered.

Please check the correctness of my assumptions. If neither of them works, please do give me some alternatives/other words to convey the same idea.

Comment: *Have* is wrong here, pretty much for the reasons you give. *Get* is fine; it's no more informal than *amazing performance*. If you're aiming at the sort of really stuffy register that would call for something like *cause you to be considered*, you're going to need to tone down that *amazing*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This level of performance would **see you considered** for any university in the entire country.

You could also use "see you considered," but if you don't like "get," you might not like "see" either.

Although there are [many instances of "see you considered"](https://www.google.com.tw/search?newwindow=1&client=firefox-b-ab&q=%22see+you+considered%22&oq=%22see+you+considered%22&gs_l=serp.3...3468.5229.0.5558.2.2.0.0.0.0.68.115.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.0.0.QpQ1mSFTt9U) online, used almost the exact same way we are using it here, I still feel like it's a little bit colloquial and idiomatic (and therefore, informal) when used in this context.

Meanwhile, "see," in this context, could mean...

1) ...view or predict as a possibility; envisage... (["see" definition 2d, Google](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=see%20definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=gmatWOmTKeX88wf404y4Cw))

2) ...ensure... (["see" definition 6, Google](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=see%20definition&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=gmatWOmTKeX88wf404y4Cw))

3) ...or both, depending on your example.

What do you think? Does this work for what you had been looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. See is certainly much better sounding to me than get. However, if you are not restricted to the verb 'considered', are there any already formal alternative expressions to convey the idea that a certain quality/achievement made it possible for someone to obtain a position/placement/award etc?

Comment: @Juncinator. This level of performance would almost certainly secure you a place at any university (of your choice) in the country.

Comment: I am not sure that the noun "level", in the given context "the amount of knowledge" can collocate with the verbs see, have, get, or make. At the same time, I think that it would better construe with the verbs guarantee, provide, permit, secure. What do you think?

Comment: @Rompey. I understand what you mean, but in the OP's OP, he had asked for phrases using "the past particle form of 'consider' in the object + participle construction" (OP). As you can see in my comment on my own answer however, once I had been unbound by this restraint, I had used "secured" as you have suggested.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang - Oh, so you did. But what's the use of sticking to what is not conforming to the appropriate usage? Wouldn't it be better to express the same idea like, say, "This level of performance would guarantee your permission to any university?"

Comment: @Rompey. I agree. Questions all quite appropriate for the OP....

Comment: @JUNCINATOR. Wow! My first time to receive a bounty. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Thanks for provided such a good answer.